# "ValueError" occurs when creating DataFrame of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, valueerror

I try to create a pandas DataFrame of a dictionary of pandas Series, and for some cases the following error is raised:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (0,
>   2)"Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed,
>   implied)ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply
>   (0, 2)

I found solutions where the same error occurred, but they are all using lists as input for their dataframe.

The error rises in the following line of my code.

```
resultRFF = pd.DataFrame({'breakdowns': breakdown['type'], 'ranks': ranksRFF})
```

`ranksRFF` and `breakdown['type']` are both pandas Series, with the same length and indices.

The error not raised in all cases, and is apparently triggered in the case where the length of these Series is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently pandas cannot handle empty series. The solution for me is to just catch those exeptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resultRFF = pd.DataFrame({'breakdowns': breakdown['type'].values, 'ranks': ranksRFF.values})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The error I had vanished, but unfortunately a new error is raised. But I found out why somethimes it goes wrong. The error occurs if the Series have length 0. Any suggestions for solving this? I'll edit the main question.

Comment: both the columns should have same number of records, you should check the length and fill the remaining records with np.nan in that case to match the length of the series.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `pd.DataFrame([{'breakdowns': breakdown['type'], 'ranks': ranksRFF}])`, I mean pass the list into DataFrame

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this gives me a dataframe of 1 by 2 cells, which is not the dataframe of 2 by the length of `breakdown['type']` and 'ranksRFF' that I am looking for.